# What is the purpose of this PHP code?

Tags: php, code-analysis

```
        self::$currentend = $cfp;
        self::$currentend = &$cfp->next;
        self::$basisend = $cfp;
        self::$basisend = &$cfp->bp;
```

What does it do?

Found [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#JAXruTdKQ_g/trunk/development/lexer/ParserGenerator/Config.php).

**UPDATE**

My question is since

```
        self::$currentend = $cfp;
        self::$currentend = &$cfp->next;
```

always evaluates to

```
        self::$currentend = &$cfp->next;
```

So why the extra line?

Comment: It sets the values for a number of static properties of a class; but without any context at all, it's difficult to say more

Comment: It could mean anything, could you paste more code?

Comment: sorry... but my marble is being cleaned right now... MORE CODE! ;-)

Comment: It sets some static properties of a class. Without seeing more code or context there is no way of giving you any more detail.

Comment: It is making coffee... `$cfp` is short for `$coffeepreparer` and `->next` makes the next coffee.... not sure about `->bp` though (mybe *bypass* because the next person wants tea).

Comment: Is there any hidden feature of PHP that we seldom know?

Comment: @yoyo: In general? I guess there are a lot of features that a lot of people seldom use. In your code? Does not look like that. How is this question related to your problem?

Comment: @yoyo - there's plenty of hidden features, but largely irrelevant to this block of code.... this does have some pointless duplication of effort, such as assigning $cfp to self::$currentend, then immediately assigning a new value to self::$currentend. But as we don't know what $cfp is, we can't say much more

Comment: The question is: What exactly do you want to know? It is just about syntax, what the individual symbols mean or what is the purpose of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP code is a C->PHP port of the [LEMON](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/getfile/sqlite/tool/lemon.c) parser generator, which includes this code:

> ```
> /* Add another configuration to the configuration list */
> struct config *Configlist_add(rp,dot)
> struct rule *rp;    /* The rule */
> int dot;            /* Index into the RHS of the rule where the dot goes */
> {
>   struct config *cfp, model;
>
>   assert( currentend!=0 );
>   model.rp = rp;
>   model.dot = dot;
>   cfp = Configtable_find(&model);
>   if( cfp==0 ){
>     cfp = newconfig();
>     cfp->rp = rp;
>     cfp->dot = dot;
>     cfp->fws = SetNew();
>     cfp->stp = 0;
>     cfp->fplp = cfp->bplp = 0;
>     cfp->next = 0;
>     cfp->bp = 0;
>     *currentend = cfp;
>     currentend = &cfp->next;
>     Configtable_insert(cfp);
>   }
>   return cfp;
> }
> ```

It's in the PHP because it was in the original C. In the original C, it writes through the `currentend` pointer to replace the contents of whatever it is pointing at (memory allocated elsewhere, probably contains garbage), and then it updates the `currentend` pointer to point to the `struct node` pointed to by `cfp->next` (which is `0`, here, which is why I think some other routine will allocate the memory for it later).

In other words, it appends the new `struct rule` to the end of a list of `struct rule`s while maintaining a pointer to the "last entry". (Well, an entry beyond the end. Where the next last-entry will go, once it exists. All of which makes accessing the end-of-the-list an O(1) operation, superb for improving list-append operations.)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what that is from, it looks weird, but I can explain:

self:: refers to the class of the current object/class.

$currentend & $basisend are variables storing variable names - that is, if the code were like this:

```
$currentend = bla1;
$currentend = bla2;
```

then it essentially evaluates to:

```
self::bla1 = $cfp;
self::bla1 =& $cfp->next;
self::bla2 = $cfp;
self::bla2 =& $cfp->bp;
```

So whatever the value behind $currentend & $basisend, they are refering to static variables within the current class.

The & is a reference operator. It basically means that you do not want to copy the variable, but "share" the variable referenced by both of the other variables. Actually, to assign a pointer to the variable.

Other than that, I have no idea from what that is or what the purpose is. But it looks funny.

Answer (score 1):

The code is incomplete as everyone has stated above, however it looks suspiciously like the Pear Config for PHP_ParserGenerator.

```
  static function Configlist_add($rp, $dot)
{
    $model = new PHP_ParserGenerator_Config;
    $model->rp = $rp;
    $model->dot = $dot;
    $cfp = self::Configtable_find($model);
    if ($cfp === 0) {
        $cfp = self::newconfig();
        $cfp->rp = $rp;
        $cfp->dot = $dot;
        $cfp->fws = array();
        $cfp->stp = 0;
        $cfp->fplp = $cfp->bplp = 0;
        $cfp->next = 0;
        $cfp->bp = 0;
        self::$currentend = $cfp;
        self::$currentend = &$cfp->next;
        self::Configtable_insert($cfp);
    }
    return $cfp;
}
```

I would suspect if you look further into the code you will find a reference to this of something similar.

Comment: Why set `self::$currentend` twice continuously?